# How to find all matches to a specific pattern and capture group with Go regexp

Tags: regex, go

I have a file with some content which I am reading into a variable with Golang. The contents of the file are as below:

```
abcd
efgh
[ijkl]
mnop
qrst
[uvwx]
yzab
```

I want to get all entries with [] into a go slice. The expected output is:
[ijkl uvwx]

However, with the current regexp in use I am able to get the below:

```
[[ijkl] [uvwx]]
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Dj3HjwzqKKo

Could I please get some help on how to capture the entry within [] with regex in Go?

Comment: Parse the file line by line and do not  use a regexp to find lines of the form [anything].

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to get through this. May not be the best way but it works. If anyone knows a better way, please do let me know.

https://play.golang.org/p/gecaKRDBzxu

Thanks!